# Refreshing old page whilst closing current page and add a action in url

Tags: javascript, php, url

I am trying to close a window after a form has been submitted and to refresh the main page, then passing information within the url for a action popup.

I have the code working fine but cant seem to pass the information on.

here is the working code

```
echo "<script>window.close();window.opener.location.reload(true);</script>";
```

I have tried the following and i know its wrong but not sure where to seek the answer as not too sure what to search for

```
<?php
// include database connection
 $id=isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : die('ERROR: Record ID not found.');
// include database connection
include '../../../assets/connect.php';

try {

    // get record ID
    // isset() is a PHP function used to verify if a value is there or not

    // delete query
    $query = "DELETE FROM investment_return Where id = '$id'";
    $stmt = $con->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindParam(1, $id);

    if($stmt->execute()){
        // redirect to read records page and 
        // tell the user record was deleted
            echo "<script>window.close();window.location.href = window.location.href + '?action=entered';</script>";
    }else{
        die('Unable to delete record.');
    }
}

// show error
catch(PDOException $exception){
    die('ERROR: ' . $exception->getMessage());
}
?>
```

As you can tell i am trying to add `?action=entered` on to the end of the url.

The above code closes the window but does not add the information needed to the end, refresh is not needed now due to it will be a new url load.

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you implement `action=enabled` ?

Comment: yes i have, im sure im missing something really basic

Comment: Please post whole code

Comment: i appreciate your time on this i have pasted the page code im my OP

Comment: My answer adds `action=enabled` to the end of your request. Your code doesn't process `action=enabled`

Comment: ok, many thanks. how would i get my code to process that request?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127953/discussion-between-magic-sudo-and-thenashone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you can use this

`window.location.href = window.location.href + "?action=entered";`

it changes location of current `window`. 
For example if your page was `https://www.google.com` it will redirect you to `https://www.google.com?action=entered`

To process your request add

```
if (isset($_GET['action'] && $_GET['action'] == 'enabled') {
    //here add your code for example
    echo "<script>alert('deleted');</script>"
}
```

Comment: i will update my OP with the code i have used with your answer, the refresh is not needed as it will load a new url with the information passing to the url but it still wont transfer the data